# Electric and magnetic dipole

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment, dipole

How does an electric dipole and magnetic dipole physically realizable? By feeding a wire with current does that become a dipole?

Comment: @Countto10: Nice... It is the most welcoming forum I've ever seen ;)

Comment: @safesphere is correct, I do apologise for being snarky. But you are expected to do some research yourself, sites like this one are useful http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hframe.html